# How to align the second level of tree diagram?

Tags: trees, forest

How can I fix this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        l sep=1cm,
        child anchor=north,
        parent anchor=south,forked edges,
        edge={->,>=latex}}
    [Circuit Elements
        [Active
        [a
        ]
        [a
        ]
        ]
        [Passive
        [b
        ]
        [b
        ]
        ]
    ]
        \end{forest}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forked edges` is equivalent to `for tree=forked edge`. So either change `forked edges` to `forked edge` or move it outside the scope of `for tree`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    l sep=1cm,
    child anchor=north,
    parent anchor=south,
    forked edge,
    edge={->,>=latex},
  }
  [Circuit Elements
    [Active
      [a
      ]
      [a
      ]
    ]
    [Passive
      [b
      ]
      [b
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: forked edge in for tree]